# Using Trigger.old and Trigger.new to detect value changes

Tags: apex, trigger

I attempted to modify what @Martin F. gave me in my first question but its still above my head. I went back and tried again. My attempt worked but it kept running an infinite loop and created 117 Jira issues. So it seems I need to check if the Approved__C checkbox was initially unchecked/false. I found some posts about 'Trigger.oldMap' and tried to incorporate it in the code. This also has not worked. Here is a sample of what I came up with.  I read another post that the Trigger.oldMap doesn't work with Future callouts, the class that goes with this trigger is a future callout

Error line:

```
if(c.Approved__c && !Trigger.oldMap(c.Id).Approved__c)
```

Error message:

> Variable does not exist: Trigger at line 9 column 25

I am completely stumped after trying to read about the trigger.oldMap use and actually editing the code to try to fix the problem. How can I fix this code so it compiles?

```
    trigger CreateIssue on CDR__c (after update) {

// Check whether current user is not JIRA agent so that we don't create an infinite loop.
if (JIRA.currentUserIsNotJiraAgent()) {

for (CDR__c c : Trigger.new) {

//Check each record if approved by approval process
if(c.Approved__c && !Trigger.oldMap(c.Id).Approved__c){ //ERROR Variable does not exist: Trigger at line 9 column 25

  // Define parameters to be used in calling Apex Class
  String objectType = 'CDR__c'; // Please change this according to the object type
  String objectId = c.id;
  String projectKey = 'CDR'; //Please change this according to the JIRA project key
  String issueType = '10001';   //Please change this according to the JIRA issue type ID
  // Calls the actual callout to create the JIRA issue.
  JIRAConnectorWebserviceCalloutCreate.createIssue(JIRA.baseUrl, JIRA.systemId, objectType, objectId, projectKey, issueType);

 }
```

Comment: `Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Approved__c` should compile.

Comment: @KeithC & AdrianLarson. I don't know how many hours I have spent trying to learn how to get this to compile. Truly appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. The compiler error messages can be misleading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Trigger.oldMap(c.Id).Approved__c
//            ^ you can't call a map as if it were a function
```

Use:

```
Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Approved__c
//            ^ you call a method on the map instead
```

---

A more verbose version of what you are trying to do may be illustrative:

```
Map<Id, CDR__c> oldMap = trigger.oldMap;
CDR__c oldRecord = oldMap.get(c.Id);
Boolean wasApproved = oldRecord.Approved__c;

if (c.Approved__c && !wasApproved)
{
    // do stuff
}
```